# Tax not applied when select Free shipping in Magento

Tags: magento

Whenever i select Free shipping or shipping method with 0.00 price, TAX is not applied to cart total. 
Here i have attached my tax configuration screenshot. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

I am using USA-CA-*  Tax rules to apply flat 8.75% tax for all order ship to California.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the Tax Class for shipping to Taxable Goods and change the products Tax Class is Taxable Goods in product information price tab.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I figured it out using the same.